# InstallShield - How to display Product Code on Install Dialog

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

This is probably really obvious, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this.

I have a Basic MSI install package created in InstallShield 2011. I haven't been able to figure out how to get the 'Product Version' field that is set on the 'General Information' page of the 'Installation Designer' to show up on the dialog form during setup.

I can see that the 'Product Name' property is displayed, but not the 'Product Version'

How do I display the 'Product Version' to the user during install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

- go to Dialogs page and select the dialog you want
- click "Edit dialog layout" link to modify the dialog
- select the control which will use the Product Version
- in its Properties pane write the following in **Text** field:

  [ProductVersion]

This is the [formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28VS.85%29.aspx) type. Please note that not all controls support formatted values in their text.

Comment: Thanks! This worked out perfectly. It wasn't obvious to me how to edit the dialogs at first.